# Weird behavior when shifting

Tags: c++, bit-shift

When I write to my SD Card using the SDCard Library from Cypress I have some challenges. Because I have to speed everything up, using `sprintf()` and similar is not possible.

The library only lets me write to the SD card in either uchars or strings. Unfortunately my values are all `int16_t`. So here is where the problem arise:

```
int16_t  ax = -15000;
         ay = -10000; 
         az = -32760;
         gx = 32760;     
         gy = 25000; 
         gz = 10;    
         mx = -10;
         my = 20;
         mz = 0;

// Then I put it into an array

char suma[] = {
    ((uint16_t) ax) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) ax) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) ay) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) ay) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) az) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) az) >> 8,

    ((uint16_t) gx) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) gx) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) gy) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) gy) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) gz) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) gz) >> 8,

    ((uint16_t) mx) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) mx) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) my) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) my) >> 8,
    ((uint16_t) mz) & 0xff,
    ((uint16_t) mz) >> 8,
    0
};
```

When I retrieve the data something is wrong. The data is fine until `gz`. It shows 10 alright but the rest is just gone.

Changing 10 to 257 eliminates the issue, and -10 is fine, meaning the error happens when I right shift a low non negative value.

What is up? I hope you have some insights :)

Comment: Assuming C or C++?

Comment: Yeah sorry, Its C++

Comment: What does gz output after adjusting it?

Comment: Well the least significant part is 10. But the next spot in the array is blank. Which is expected behavior but then it is as if the program bugs out. Instead of writing the next array values (i.e. mx lower and mx upper) it just stops. As if the code had a break line and stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In converting an `int16_t` to a uint16 and then to a `char`, you're likely ending up sending a `null char` (\0) to the library.

The library - which only accepts `char[]` or `string` - probably casts the former to a c string, which are terminated with a `null char`. Meaning your most significant byte (0x00) is terminating the string early. Any uint16 under 257 will result in a null char in the most significant spot.

e.g:

```
0000 0000 = [0, 0] = [0x00, 0x00]   // 2 null chars, only the first will get across
0001 0000 = [1, 0] = [0x01, 0x00]   // null char
                                    // ...
1111 0000 = [256, 0] = [0xff, 0x00] // null char
1111 0001 = [256, 1] = [0xff, 0x01] // not null char
```

Try explicitly casting your char[] to an std::string and specifying the size of it. ex:

```
std::string s("ab\0c", 4);
```

Comment: I believe you are correct. What I observe matches what you describe. How do you propose I manage this problem?

I could perhaps add a comparative function, like a **for** loop saying "if a value is under 257 and larger than -1. Add 33"  Then in my postprocessing, I do a check for every upper binary part that has 33in it.
Ofcourse that would mean that every value with 00100001 in the upper part would be affacted :/

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, try first with an explicit cast to an std::string with the size of the string. If that doesn't work, see if the library accepts a pointer to a string, beyond that, you may have to modify the library yourself to support null chars.

Comment: @AndreasHD well, after you cast to a uint16_t, you don't have to worry about numbers < 0, but if you're trying to write actual binary to a file on the SD card, you'd want to keep 0x00 bytes, so changing the values might not be what you want.